# Merging of 2 packages in oracle using toad

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, package

I have 2 packages which contains more than 20 functions and procedures.  The two procedures are dependent to other packages, but not to each other.  So I have to delete all the dependencies and of the two packages and merge them to one single package.I am using toad 9.0 and oracle database 10g.

Please tell me how I can do this using toad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Package A and Package B which 2 these packages contains more than 20 functions and procedure. 2 of the procedure from Package A and Package B dependent to other package, let say Package C. So you want to delete the dependencies of procedure in Package A and Package B and merge Package A and Package B. Am i right?.

In this case you can just copy the procedure from Package B and paste in Package A, declare those functions and procedures in Package A and compile Package A.

Comment: Hi chinna Thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: Hi. Please click as answer if it helps you. Thanks